# What algorithm do I use to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

The UVA programming competition problems from 2016 are here: http://acm.cs.virginia.edu/data/2016-contest.pdf.
Problem I is interesting. A summary of the problem is as follows.

> A restaurant has n types of foods, and m people want to order. Each person wants one of k foods (each of which is listed in the n types before). Each food the restaurant has can only be served once. Is it possible to satisfy everyone?

An example would be as follows:

> A restuarant has a pancakes, waffles, and muffins.  
> Tom wants pancakes.  
> Suzy wants pancakes or waffles.  
> Joe wants muffins or waffles.

In this case, each person can be satisfied (Tom with pancakes, Suzy with waffles, and Joe with muffins).
What algorithm would I use to solve this problem completely (not just simplify it)? Where can I find pseudocode for it?

Comment: If you downvote, please say why.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but it's most likely due to the nature of the question.. It's not a code issue question.. So it's unrelated to StackOverflow..

Comment: By the way, *Question is unclear or shows no research attempt* is on the tooltip for the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem might be solved with bipartite matching using Ford-Fulkerson algorithm.
The examples and explanation may be found here  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/